# Mootools Delay Issue

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm ultimately trying to delay the fade out by 5 seconds (page loads, 5 seconds later the fade out happens). But right now the bit of code below throwing a "delay is not a function" error.

```
el.fade('out').get('tween').chain(function(){
    el.destroy();
}).delay(5000);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works where `el` is a valid element. I used an item with id of `demoitem` to test it, so:

```
var el = $('demoitem');
(function(){
    el.fade('out').get('tween');
    el.destroy();
}).delay(5000);
```

[delay()](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Function#Function:delay) is a function which is can be chained to functions, not to the chain of an HTMLElement.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's helped me in a very tight spot, with a deadline looming :D

Answer (score 1):

Delay is a function method, this should work:

```
el.fade('out').get('tween').chain(function(){
    el.destroy();
}.delay(5000));
```

Comment: No go. Error from firebug: this.$chain.shift().apply is not a function

Comment: Hmm not sure on that, I suppose you could just go with: setTimeout(function() { /* code */ }, 5000);

Comment: `.delay()` has to be added to a function, in this case encapsulate the code inside an anonymous function that's enclosed in parens - like this: `(function(){ /* your code goes into this block */ }).delay(5000)`

Comment: so he's missing a ) after } and before .delay. still - this IS the better reply as it insures continuity and that the el won't be removed before the tween is over.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
    var el = $('fade');
    el.fade('out').get('tween');
    el.destroy();
}).delay(5000);
```